# Can we use custom metadata type records in validation rule in salesforce?

Tags: validation-rule, custom-metadata

I was trying to use custom metadata type in validation rule. 
My use case is i want a restriction on digits in phone number on various objects in managed package.I want to give flexibility to subscribers so that they can edit min and max length of phone. I created custom metadata type records and i want to access them in validation rule ..

can anyone suggest me How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom metadata types are not yet available for Validation Rules.  You still need to use Hierarchical Custom Settings if you want to have some configuration value affect a VR.

Answer (score 5):

As of Spring '18 you can use Custom metadata types in Validation rules. Its available from 11th Feb 2018 in all Orgs and is already available in a few sandboxes to try out.

```
$CustomMetadata.CustomMetadataTypeAPIName.RecordAPIName.FieldAPIName
```